# CSS media queries and mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, media

I've spent a while searching for an answer to this now, and I'm starting to think there's something I've fundamentally misunderstood about `CSS media queries`.

I have a website consisting of a centered block with `max-width: 960px` where the `body` has `min-width: 600px`.

This works fine for browser windows of varying widths on PC, but on mobile, the block is considered to have `width` `960px` and is stretched to the full width of the screen. While I do want the block to stretch, I would like the logical width to be smaller so that the contents will appear larger on screen.

I imagine the solution is to set the `width` of the `body` to `600px` on small devices, but I am unsure how to achieve this. I naively attempted to use `@media (max-width: 480px)` which didn't work. I presume this is because the `width` has already been calculated to `960px`, but then, why would it work in other cases?

I hope you can help me understand this and how to achieve the logically narrower block.
Cheers!

Comment: Could you add an example? It's really hard to understand the problem just written down in a text :( Sorry.

Comment: @QuentinAlbert, here you go:

https://codepen.io/krainert/pen/QWLNjaP

I managed to make this (almost) work with this line:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Now, however, the page starts zoomed in on mobile.